# ESLint: `parserOptions.project` not configured to point at your project tsconfig.json files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

In my NX Workspace, I have a NestJS-Angular project. When I run `nx lint`, I get the following error:

```
Error: You have attempted to use a lint rule which requires the full TypeScript type-checker to be available, but you do not have `parserOptions.project` configured to point at your project tsconfig.json files in the relevant TypeScript file "overrides" block of your project ESLint config `apps/client/.eslintrc.json`

Please see https://nx.dev/guides/eslint for full guidance on how to resolve this issue.
```

I have browsed the link that is mentioned and as you can see, I have added `parserOptions.project` in my `.eslintrc.json` file however, the error is still there.

```
{
  "extends": ["../../.eslintrc.json"],
  "ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["/apps/client/tsconfig.*?.json"]
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@nrwl/nx/angular",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "learning",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "learning",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "no-empty-function": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/angular-template"],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove slash in parserOptions.project in apps/client